# How to get the block of new template magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

i installed this theme http://magento2.flytheme.net/themes/sm_shop4u/default/ and i miss many block in my home page such as featured products , Deals of the week so how can i get them back or i have to create new block but how to know the right place to put them under featured product?? i am sorry if i can't explain very well i am new in magento 2 please help me 
[image]

Comment: You need to call that all block on home page from backend

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: how to call them and how to know the right order

Comment: For that you need to check home page from backend.

Comment: I get the name of blocks but how to put on them products

Comment: You can call via layout or call via editing page.

Comment: See this links : http://www.blogtreat.com/magento-2-how-to-call-cms-static-block-in-phtml-file/
https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/call-a-static-block-on-cmc-page/
https://webkul.com/blog/call-phtml-file-cms-page-magento2/

Comment: jsut one think the block name are there and the code is there so  am supposed to change the block name or to change in code and iam really sorry for not explainnig well